# How do I check if the list contains an item, one of which attributes is the same as provided (given it's also a list)

Tags: ansible

Well, basically I receive a list of file systems from `community.general.btrfs_info`:

```
- name: Query information about mounted btrfs filesystems
  community.general.btrfs_info:
  register: btrfs_facts
  become: true
```

And I want to create a certain multi-device file system, if it doesn't yet exist. So, I need a condition which will check if the file systems' list contains a file system, which attribute 'devices' will be exactly the list of `['/dev/sda1', 'dev/sdb1']` (no matter the position of its elements).

The closest I got is:

```
- not btrfs_facts.filesystems|selectattr('devices', 'contains', '/dev/sda1')
- not btrfs_facts.filesystems|selectattr('devices', 'contains', '/dev/sdb1')
```

But this also works if I have two lists, one of which has `'/dev/sda1'`, and another one `'/dev/sdb1'`. I tried to use `selectattr('devices', 'contains', ['/dev/sda1', '/dev/sdb1'])` but that doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried to go with the 'difference' filter, but turns out it doesn't actually output pure difference.

```
(btrfs_facts.filesystems|selectattr('devices', 'contains', '/dev/sda5')|first).devices|difference(['/dev/sda5', '/dev/sdb1'])
```

I would appreciate it if someone helped me out.

For the context, this is a sample content of `btrfs_facts` in the state when no change is needed:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "filesystems": [
            {
                "default_subvolume": null,
                "devices": [
                    "/dev/sda1",
                    "/dev/sdb1"
                ],
                "label": "raid",
                "subvolumes": [],
                "uuid": "310fb301-e4c1-492f-bc94-93816ba4206b"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And in the state that the change is needed:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "filesystems": [
            {
                "default_subvolume": null,
                "devices": [
                    "/dev/sdb1"
                ],
                "label": "foo",
                "subvolumes": [],
                "uuid": "9928c5a5-e91c-4fdc-a0f5-55eac5edbe25"
            },
            {
                "default_subvolume": null,
                "devices": [
                    "/dev/sda1"
                ],
                "label": "raid",
                "subvolumes": [],
                "uuid": "310fb301-e4c1-492f-bc94-93816ba4206b"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: Given the simplified filesystems for testing

```yaml
    btrfs_facts:
      filesystems:
        - label: raid
          uuid: a1
          devices: [/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1]
        - label: raid
          uuid: a2
          devices: [/dev/sda2]
        - label: raid
          uuid: a3
          devices: [/dev/sdb2]
        - label: raid
          uuid: a4
          devices: [/dev/sdd1, /dev/sdc1]
```

Select items where the devices match a list, for example `[/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1]`. The order of the items in the list may vary.

A: There are more options.

**1. Iterate the list of the devices**

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ result|d(btrfs_facts.filesystems)|
                    selectattr('devices', 'contains', item) }}"
      loop: "{{ slist }}"
      vars:
        slist: [/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1]
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
    - devices: [/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1]
      label: raid
      uuid: a1
```

**2. Convert the list to a dictionary**

Join the lists of devices and use them as the keys

```yaml
  fs_keys: "{{ btrfs_facts.filesystems|
               map(attribute='devices')|
               map('sort')|
               map('join') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  fs_keys:
  - /dev/sda1/dev/sdb1
  - /dev/sda2
  - /dev/sdb2
  - /dev/sdc1/dev/sdd1
```

and create a dictionary

```yaml
  fs_dict: "{{ dict(fs_keys|zip(btrfs_facts.filesystems)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  fs_dict:
    /dev/sda1/dev/sdb1:
      devices: [/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1]
      label: raid
      uuid: a1
    /dev/sda2:
      devices: [/dev/sda2]
      label: raid
      uuid: a2
    /dev/sdb2:
      devices: [/dev/sdb2]
      label: raid
      uuid: a3
    /dev/sdc1/dev/sdd1:
      devices: [/dev/sdd1, /dev/sdc1]
      label: raid
      uuid: a4
```

Now, the search is trivial. The below *set_fact* gives the same result. The advantage of this one is that you don't need the iteration. You can put this declaration of *result* also into the *vars* if you want to.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ fs_dict[slist|sort|join] }}"
      vars:
        slist: [/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1]
```

Other examples

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ fs_dict[item|sort|join] }}"
      loop:
        - [/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1]
        - [/dev/sdc1, /dev/sdd1]
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => (item=['/dev/sda1', '/dev/sdb1']) => 
  msg:
    devices: [/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1]
    label: raid
    uuid: a1
ok: [test_01] => (item=['/dev/sdc1', '/dev/sdd1']) => 
  msg:
    devices: [/dev/sdd1, /dev/sdc1]
    label: raid
    uuid: a4
```

the selection as well

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ select_keys|map('extract', fs_dict) }}"
      vars:
        select_lists:
        - [/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1]
        - [/dev/sdc1, /dev/sdd1]
        select_keys: "{{ select_lists|map('sort')|map('join') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
    - devices: [/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1]
      label: raid
      uuid: a1
    - devices: [/dev/sdd1, /dev/sdc1]
      label: raid
      uuid: a4
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    btrfs_facts:
      filesystems:
        - label: raid
          uuid: a1
          devices: [/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1]
        - label: raid
          uuid: a2
          devices: [/dev/sda2]
        - label: raid
          uuid: a3
          devices: [/dev/sdb2]
        - label: raid
          uuid: a4
          devices: [/dev/sdd1, /dev/sdc1]

    fs_keys: "{{ btrfs_facts.filesystems|
                 map(attribute='devices')|
                 map('sort')|
                 map('join') }}"
    fs_dict: "{{ dict(fs_keys|zip(btrfs_facts.filesystems)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: fs_keys

    - debug:
        var: fs_dict|to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ fs_dict[item|sort|join] }}"
      loop:
        - [/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1]
        - [/dev/sdc1, /dev/sdd1]

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ select_keys|map('extract', fs_dict) }}"
      vars:
        select_lists:
        - [/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1]
        - [/dev/sdc1, /dev/sdd1]
        select_keys: "{{ select_lists|map('sort')|map('join') }}"
```

Comment: Oh, I see the pattern, thanks. However, the solution I found seems slightly shorter.

Comment: It depends on how often you will use it. Use yours if it is just a one-off. If you should repeat the search put *fs_keys* and *fs_dict* into the *vars* and use `fs_dict[slist|sort|join]`. I added more examples.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick

```
- not (btrfs_facts.filesystems|selectattr('devices', 'contains', '/dev/sda1')|first).devices == ['/dev/sda1', '/dev/sdb1']
```

But I still wonder if there is a simpler solution.